# I selected checkboxes, I run a function and update something. After the execution, I want to deselect those checkboxes in the UI

Tags: angular-material

HTML for checkbox:

<ng-container *ngFor="let item of n; let i=index ">

<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.isSelected" (change)="checkIfAllSelected()"
(click)="$event.stopPropagation();">

ts file with the update function:

update(){

this.selected = this.n.filter(n1 => n1.isSelected === true);

let selectedIds = this.selected.map(x => x.id);

this._nService.updateService(selectedIds)
.then(resp => {

```
  if (resp) {

    
    for(var i = 0;i<this.n.length;i++){
      if(selectedIds.some(id => id === this.n[i].id)){
        this.n[i].isRead = true;
        console.log(this.n[i].id);
      }
    }
  }
}).catch(err => {
  this._alertService.showAlert(AlertType.ERROR);
});
```

}

checkIfAllSelected() {

this.selectedAll = this.n.every(function(item:any) {

```
  return item.isSelected == true;

})
```

}